# Изменить цветовой канал, яркость видео файла

Tags: c++, qt, видео, ffmpeg

Реализую видеоплеер с использованием QMediaPlayer. Хочу добавить функцию редактирования при помощи ffmpeg. Никто не подскажет, как редактировать загруженное видео, применить к нему фильтры ffmpeg, возможно нужно разбить его на кадры.
Либо если для этого вы посоветуете открыть видеофайл с помощью ffmpeg, скажите, как тогда вывести его в Qt. 
Редактировать означает изменить цветовой канал или яркость.

Comment: Для ответа на Ваш вопрос придётся сменить ярлык с гида на творца и самому написать всё приложение целиком. И всё же, что конкретно в перечисленном функционале поставило Вас в тупик и нивелировало достойную одобрения мысль о возможности самостоятельной реализации кода?

Answer (score 4):

Изучите [API FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/index.html) (или воспользуйтесь моим [C++ враппером](https://github.com/h4tr3d/avcpp) (но работа с фильтрами там не закончена)), посмотрите [на примеры](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/examples.html). Изучите [список поддерживаемых фильтров и их опций](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html). Да и прочей [документации](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html), особенно в секции "Component Documentation", там даны списки поддерживаемых форматов, кодеков, их опций и так далее, что будет необходимо в работе.

После чего приступайте к реализации. Начните с реализации алгоритмов в виде консольных приложений: дали файл на вход, применили преобразования, записали на выход - в таких примерах будет проще локализовывать ошибки (а они будут, это я вам гарантирую - API FFmpeg не для слабых духом, ну а все подводные камни я вам за неделю рассказать не смогу, при том, что регулярно открываются новые). В любом случае, уже при конкретных можно уже задавать конкретные вопросы.

И да, фильтры FFmpeg вполне можно использовать независимо от других компонент - главное правильно создайте и заполните `AVFrame`ы, которые будете ему скармливать. Учтите, что в фильтров может быть задержка, что значит - запихнув один кадр, вы не обязательно получите преобразованный на выходе, а получите его только после N скормленных на вход кадров - некоторые фильтры зависят от результатов обработки соседних кадров. В таких случаях нужно, в конце, пропихнуть оставшиеся кадры отправкой `NULL`-фреймов. Возможно и другая ситуация, когда на один отправленный фрейм у вас будет N выходных.